# Should I upgrade my town hall to 9?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I am a near max th8 with 5 builders. I have overflowing elixir I am now using dragons to use it but I am not able to spend it yet. My gold storage is completely opposite I have around 15 lac gold+10 lacs in Treasury and I am left with 3 upgrades of 25 lac each , I am really having a big deficiency of gold after those three upgrades I have to do the following:-

1. Upgrade golem to level 2
2. Upgrade Valkyrie to level 2
3. Upgrade hogs to level 4
4. Upgrade minions from 2 to 4
5. Poison is still level 1
6. Earthquake is also level 1
7. Heal spell to level 5
8. One levels of healer wall breaker and barbarian.
9. And 215 walls to level 8

My builders are free all time all elixir I  get is getting wasted I have only 70000 dark elixir if I spend it on golem or Valkyrie then how will I get that huge amount back again? 
My real question is the title. I have seen many people saying that the time I am wasting I should fill my all storages and go to th9 a bit earlier it will make me progress faster in game . And if no then how do I quickly fill my storages again and again for remaining upgrades and next town hall? I have checked many youtube guides and internet also that was not useful. What do I do?

Comment: Note: 'lakh' is Indian English only, most other English speakers won't know what it means.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

i will say No!

first thing to do is upgrade all the walls ik its one of the hardest things in the game and it takes long time but when you upgrade your townhall it will be MUCH harder for you to gain Resources and the walls will take even longer to upgrade

so upgrade them now Before you level up your townhall

Comment: I am left with 215 walls to upgrade each piece costs 2.5 lacs of gold and the max storage is 6 million. I am already in a deficiency of gold to upgrade teslas upgrading those walls will take around 2 months I know it is not right to upgrade a bit earlier but I am so confused that why do I waste 2 months of building time some say that if I upgrade to th9 then I will be able to farm very much more efficiently but dude I really don't know what Is right I have not seen th9 so I can't say . Do you have any method that can help me gain gold very quickly and get those walls done? And man dark elixir

Comment: Thanks man ..I thought I could not do it but when you said that I should do it then I tried it is not as difficult as I thought I just upgraded 50 walls in 3 days so I won't be having much problems and the dark elixir..I am somehow able to loot 10k to 20k dark elixir per day it comes on its own while collecting gold